# Direct sum representations of set of all real valued continuous functions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Define $X={\{f \in C(\mathbb{R}) : f(x)=f(-x)}\}$.
Then there exists two subspaces $X_1$ and $X_2$ of $C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $C(\mathbb{R})=X \oplus X_1=X \oplus X_2$ but $X_1 \cap X_2={\{0}\}$?
I was able to think one representation by choosing $X_1$ to be the set of all odd continuous functions, but to construct $X_2$, I could not think. Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: take the even ones! in the end you actually do not care as you only need to find a linear camplement, but the even ones are useful as you can then have a lovely way as writing a function as a sum of an even and an odd one!

Comment: @Enkidu That doesn't give $X\oplus X_1=X\oplus X_2$.

Comment: I am sorry, seems I did not read carefully enough.